# Active Directory SubDomains with repeated logins?

Tags: active-directory

Simple question: is it possible to have two active directory domains, one being parent to the other (a forest) and have two user accounts with the same login, one in each domain ?

Thanks

Fábio

Comment: Do you mean this:

DomainA\user and DomainB.DomainA\user?

Comment: yes. That's what I mean. Just its DomainA.net/user and DomainB.DomainA.net/user and DomainC.DomainA.net/user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can - but it's fairly silly to do that. In AD, domains in the same tree will trust each other, so you can assign rights for resources in Domain A to a user in Domain B, and vice-versa. No need to make accounts with the same names.